# API not returning proper shipping methods when calling shoppingCartShippingList

Tags: magento-enterprise, api, shipping-methods

I am trying to pull the same sipping methods that Magento shows on the front end for a product via the API, but I'm not getting the desired results.  Please see my code below:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient("https://www.mydomain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
$sessionId = $proxy->login("myuser", "mypass");

$filter = array (
    'complex_filter' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array ('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,grouped,configurable,bundle')
        )
    )
);

$store_view = '1';
$customer = array (
    'firstname' => 'testFirstName',
    'lastname' => 'testLastName',
    'email' => 'testapi@mydomain.com',
    'mode' => 'guest',
    'website_id' => '1',
    'store_id' => '1',
    'group_id' => '1'
);
$customerAddress = array (
    array (
        'mode' => 'billing',
        'firstname' => 'testFirstName',
        'lastname' => 'testLastName',
        'street' => '123 Elm Street',
        'city' => 'Kansas City',
        'region' => 'KS',
        'postcode' => '66101',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'telephone' => '123456789',
        'is_default_billing' => 1
    ),
    array (
        'mode' => 'shipping',
        'firstname' => 'testFirstName',
        'lastname' => 'testLastName',
        'street' => '123 Elm Street',
        'city' => 'Kansas City',
        'region' => 'KS',
        'postcode' => '66101',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'telephone' => '123456789',
        'is_default_shipping' => 1
    )
);

$cart = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, $store_view);
$cartCustomer = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $cart, $customer, $store_view);
$cartAddresses = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId, $cart, $customerAddress, $store_view);

$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filter);

foreach ($result as $product) {
    print_r ($product);
    $add = array (
        array (
            'product_id' => $product->product_id,
            'sku' => $product->sku,
            'qty' => '1',
            'options' => null,
            'bundle_option' => null,
            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
            'links' => null
        )
    );
    $cart_add = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cart, $add, $store_view);
    $cartInfo = $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, $cart);
    $cartShipping = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, $cart, $store_view);
    print_r ($cartShipping);
    exit;
}
```

When I run this, the results are:

The product I'm adding to the cart....

```
stdClass Object
(
    [product_id] => 71
    [sku] => BB-514
    [name] => Stainless Steel Hanging Ash Bucket
    [set] => 10
    [type] => simple
    [category_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1073
            [1] => 1166
            [2] => 1626
        )

    [website_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

Shipping...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => freeshipping_freeshipping
            [carrier] => freeshipping
            [carrier_title] => Free Shipping
            [method] => freeshipping
            [method_title] => Free
            [price] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => productrate_productrate
            [carrier] => productrate
            [carrier_title] => Ground
            [method] => productrate
            [method_title] => Shipping
            [price] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => dropship_error
            [carrier] => dropship
            [carrier_title] => Shipping
            [price] => 0
        )

)
```

When I add the product via our website, and use the same customer details, I am shown that the only available shipping method for this product is "FedEx Home Delivery (1-7 Days)" for a cost of $12.77, and this is what it should be and what I'm expecting to see via the API.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but I just can't find it.  An extra set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same exact problem when using the SOAP API V2. Except that for me I get NO shipping results just an empty array. I believe that SOAP API V2 is **broken** for **shoppingCartShippingList** function.

However I am able to get the desired results using SOAP API V1. Using the following test code.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('api-user', 'api-pass');

$cartId = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create', array() );

// load the customer list and select ID 2 from the list
$complexFilter = array(
    'entity_id' => array('eq' => '2')
);
$customerList = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.list', array($complexFilter));
$customer = $customerList[0];
$customer['mode'] = 'customer';

// Set the customer to quote/cart
$resultCustomerSet = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_customer.set', array($cartId, $customer) );

// load the product list and select product from the list
$productFilter = array('product_id' => array('eq' => '859') );
$productList = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list',array($productFilter));
$product = $productList[0];
$product['qty'] = 1;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($product);
echo '</pre>';

// Add product to Cart
$resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId,'cart_product.add', array($cartId,array($product)) );

// Load customers address list
$addressList = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer_address.list', $customer['customer_id']);

$shipping = $addressList[2];
$shipping['mode'] = 'shipping';
$shipping['is_default_shipping'] = 1;//Optional
$shipping['is_default_billing'] = 0;//Optional

$billing = $addressList[2];
$billing['mode'] = 'billing';
$billing['is_default_shipping'] = 0;//Optional

$address = array(
    $shipping,
    $billing
);

// Set customers Address to quote/cart
$resultCustomerAddresses = $proxy->call($sessionId,'cart_customer.addresses', array($cartId,$address) );

// Get cart/quote info
$cartInfo = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart.info', $cartId);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($cartInfo);
echo '</pre>';

// Get shipping method list
$shippingList = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_shipping.list', $cartId);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($shippingList);
echo '</pre>';

// If you don't need the session anymore
$proxy->endSession($sessionId);
```

The $cartInfo call is optional, I use it to check the quote/cart contents. Also the product and customer information is dependent on your environment. I suggest outputting those arrays to see your options and using id's you know exist, you may not have a test customer that has an address at $addressList[2]!